# Intellij save console output to unique file per run

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I modified the Run/Debug Configuration so that the console is saved to a file. However, on successive runs, the file is overwritten with the console from the most recent run. Sometimes, I need to go back to previous runs and check something but I'm really forgetful and don't remember to rename the file before re-running. [image: Screentshot of setting 'Save console output to file:']

How can I save the console output to a file unique to the instance of the run?

Comment: Unfortunately, It's not possible at the moment, please upvote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-136279.